# Excel how to set a given value to date ranges

Tags: vba, excel, date

I need to automatically set a value of 8.45 hours work for the winter schedule (01 October till 15 June) and 6 hours work for a summer schedule (16 June till 30 September) for a time sheet done in Microsoft Excel.

The equation I am trying is the following:

```
=IF(AND(DATE($G$1,6, DAY(15))>=(DATE($G$1-1, 10, DAY(1))));(DATE($G$1,6, DAY(15))<A8;8.45;"")
```

But this keeps on returning formula errors and this still omits the rate value for the summer schedule.

- $G$1 is the year that is manually inputted for the yearly time sheet.
- A8 is the current date.

Any guidance into this equation would be appreciate.

With best regards Fab

Edit

Thanks DirkReichel, Scott Craner, Alex Bell, Michael Uray for your great intervention.

I tried all the suggestions but some returned a =VALUE error and some did not omit the winter schedule as from the 1 October ->

Comment: I'm a bit confused... why does your `Date` use `,` but your `If` seperate with `;`? Shouldn't they all be the same?

Comment: @DirkReichel good catch.  I totally missed that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct equation:

```
=IF(AND(DATE($G$1,9,30)>=A8,DATE($G$1,6,15)<=A8),6,8.45)
```

The equation checks the current date being A8 and checks if it falls withing the summer period (date range). If current date falls within the summer period the value is returned to 6, if the current date falls outside the summer period, it returns a value of 8.45.

Thanks to all that guided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(DATE($G$1,6,15)>=A8,DATE($G$1-1,10, 1)<=A8),8.45,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the regional settings, you may use comma "`,`" instead of "`;`" as shown in the following example:

```
=IF(AND(NOW()>DATEVALUE("6/15/2016"), NOW()<DATEVALUE("9/1/2016")),6,8.45)
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: The use of `;` instead of `,` is a regional setting as far as I'm aware - see [here](http://superuser.com/q/509742/5308) for example

Comment: @barrowc Even though it should be clearly specified; otherwise, it well could be the cause of the error. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should work for you:

A1 is the date which gets checked, the formula is placed in B1.
On this way you can pull down a list of dates and formulas in your sheet.

```
=IF(AND(A1>DATE(YEAR(A1),6,15),A1<DATE(YEAR(A1),8,1)),6,8.45)
```

It checks if the data is in the range of YYYY-06-15 and YYYY-08-01 and sets then the output to 6, or if it is not in this range to 8.45

I did test it with e German Excel Version with the following formula and I translated it then manually in Notepad to the English formula version.

```
=WENN(UND(A1>DATUM(JAHR(A1);6;15);A1<DATUM(JAHR(A1);8;1));6;8,45)
```

I hope my formula translation will work for you in the English Excel version.

Comment: Ein Tipp von mir: du musst die Formel nicht übersetzen. Öffne einfach den VBA-Editor und gib im Direktfenster `?Selection.Formula` ein (während die Zelle mit der Formel ausgewählt ist). So bekommst du die englische Schreibweise als Ausgabe. Geht auch andersrum: Zelle auswählen und `Selection.Formula = "=SUM(A1:B2)"` und in der Zelle steht es dann in deutsch. ;)